# Jquery .click event

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make it so when they click on a `<tr>` it will open up a dialog which works just fine.  However within this `<tr>` I have an input check box that I need to allow them to click on without opening up the dialog.  How is this possible?

```
$('#messageContainer tr').click(function () {
    var masterMessageID = $(this).attr('messageID');
    var replyToID = $(this).attr('replyToID');

    buildDialog(this.id, masterMessageID, replyToID);
    $(this).removeClass('messageNew');
});
```

HTML:

```
<tr replytoid="3" messageid="7078" id="16">
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="checkAll"></td>
    <td>John Doe</td>
    <td>sdfsdf</td>
    <td>3/14/2012 1:29:47 PM</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stop the propagation of the click:

```
$('#messageContainer tr :checkbox').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Will it work for bubbling down events? Wouldn't the tr click be called first if the events bubble down?

Comment: @SKS Events bubble up, not down.

Comment: @RichardD I think you should check http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code:

```
$('#messageContainer tr input:checkbox').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will stop the click on the checkbox from propagating up to the tr.

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/U5LBR/1/

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Changed from `.is(':checkbox')` to check for `e.target.type`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/WJ8hH/2/)

```
$('#messageContainer tr').click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.type && e.target.type == 'checkbox') {
       e.stopPropagation(); //stop bubbling
       return;
    }

    var masterMessageID = $(this).attr('messageID');
    var replyToID = $(this).attr('replyToID');

    buildDialog(this.id, masterMessageID, replyToID);
    $(this).removeClass('messageNew');
});
```

Comment: @Alnitak I tried .not() but could not get it to work correctly.

Comment: @JamesWilson I think Guffa has a better solution. In case if you don't want an additional handler, then see my edits above.

Comment: @SKS Alright, I tried Guffa's and it seems to work.  I haven't tested it in any old old browser.  But it seems to do the trick for me in current versions of FF and IE.

Comment: @JamesWilson the propagation was the real fault, I was just proposing `.not()` instead of `!(...).is()`

Answer (score 0):

Check this

Add event.stopPropagation() in checkbox. It will stop the event bubbling.

```
$('#messageContainer tr').click(function () {
$('#popup').toggle();
});

$('#messageContainer input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(e){
alert('Checked');
 e.stopPropagation();

})
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/JLDzq/1/

Comment: I am not too familiar with bubbling.  Would the first answer the one that just adds 'e.stopPropagation();' be good or bad?

Comment: First answer is doing the same.